# How do I source geoJSON coordinates to SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, geojson

I have a geoJSON file containing LINESTRING type coordinates (an electricity grid in Africa).

I would like to parse it and insert into SQL Server database as a `Geography` type (to visualize in Tableau later).

Using the below code allows me to import all of the values from JSON file apart from Coordinates which remains NULL. What should I do to have the geography-type data in the Coordinates column?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.testGeographyJSON
GO

CREATE TABLE testGeographyJSON 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Country NVARCHAR(300),
    Operator NVARCHAR(300),
    Status NVARCHAR(300),
    voltage_kV FLOAT(12),
    length_km FLOAT(12),
    Coordinates GEOGRAPHY
)

DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @g GEOGRAPHY;

-- load the geojson into the variable
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\africagrid20170906final.geojson', SINGLE_CLOB) as JSON


INSERT INTO dbo.testGeographyJSON (Country, Operator, Status, voltage_kV, length_km, Coordinates)
    SELECT
        Country, Operator, Status,
        voltage_kV, length_km,
        @g.STBuffer(1).ToString()
    FROM
        OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.features')
    WITH 
        (Country NVARCHAR(300) '$.properties.country',
         Operator NVARCHAR(300) '$.properties.voltage_kV',
         Status NVARCHAR(300) '$.properties.status',
         voltage_kV FLOAT(12) '$.properties.voltage_kV',
         length_km FLOAT(12) '$.properties.length_km'
        )
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the dataset with the coordinates. I have solutions for polygons multipolygons but may have to tweak it if you have lines.